# How to make a panel transparent like glass

Tags: c#, winforms

How to give c# panel glass like transparency something similar to this ([image after clicking on show desktop of windows 7](http://windows-7-tips-tricks.com/Top_100_Windows_7_Tips_Tricks/Top_100_Windows_7_Tips_Tricks_files/Windows%207%20Tips%20Tricks%20-%20Have%20a%20Peek.jpg)) ? And will it work properly under windows XP ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: No I don't want to have transparency like that. I want to have glass like feeling and I don't want my panel to have blur effect like aero. I after something like the project "Glass panel" project given in Mattias's answer but I'm having trouble converting it to c#

Comment: @Hans Passant, What I am working on is a school project. Moreover I want to learn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this code project [GlassPanel](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/static/GlassPanel.aspx).
This tutorial may also help [ExtendGlass](http://www.wpftutorial.net/ExtendGlass.html)

Comment: glass panel is written in vb.net , how to use it in c# ?. And I don't want my panel have the  blur effect

Comment: Here is a good tutorial that shows you how to make a transparent form:http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial105_Transparent-forms-(form-opacity).html

Comment: I dont think thier is any easy way to do this. But i would use the tutorial mention above. To get the best effect I whould also add a background picture and remove the form header that contains the Min/Maximize and exit buttons.

Comment: There is a C# version of the GlassPanel. Someone posted it inside message section (see reply to "Nice article"). Can you tell me where I should copy paste the codes (in a class or form) ?